# How can I convert the integer output of an enum to a two character string?

Tags: c#

For the following Enum:

```
public enum ContentKey {
    Menu = 0,
    Article = 1,
    FavoritesList = 2
};
```

The enum ContentKey returns an integer 0,1,2.  How can I convert or cast this so that it returns a two digit zero padded string "00", "01" .. "99" etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call `ToString` you can use the format string `"00"` to ensure that you get at least two digits:

```
string result = ((int)contentKey).ToString("00");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    String.Format("{0:00}", (int)<youEnum>),
```

and for enum you only need to do this

```
public enum ContentKey {
Menu = 0,
Article,
FavoritesList
```

};

it will automaticly set the the values for you

Comment: You will automatically set the value for me? How?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can pad an int with 0s.

If you want to do it with a string however, you can use:

```
string text = value.ToString("00");
```

Comment: If 'value' is an enum, this doesn't work. The only valid format strings for enums are G/F/D/X https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3s1ez6e(v=vs.110).aspx